# Wordpress on Google cloud platform

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, internal-server-error, server-error

I activated wordfence security on wordpress installation on Google cloud platform and now the site is showing server error.
Usually i use file manager to fix it,but cant find a way to do that on Google cloud platform.
Any idea how to solve this issue?
Thx

Comment: If your WordPress is hosted on a VM, you can set up a connection via SSH using a terminal app or another protocol like SCP or SFTP. In any case, you need to provide more details on your setup to get better assistance. If this is server related, you might want to ask on: https://serverfault.com/

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance